# How can I boot into Ubuntu with a linux kernel with an earlier version?

Tags: kernel

Part of the output of `ls -ld /usr/src/linux-headers*` on ubuntu 12.04 is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jun  4  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-45
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jun  4  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-45-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jun 14  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-48
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jun 14  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-48-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jul 12  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-49
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jul 12  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-49-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Sep  4  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-51
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Sep  4  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-51-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Sep  8  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-53
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Sep  8  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-53-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Oct 21  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-54
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Oct 21  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-54-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Dec 24  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-57
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Dec 24  2013 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-57-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Jan  5  2014 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-58
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Jan  5  2014 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-58-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Feb 25  2014 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-59
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Feb 25  2014 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-59-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Mar 12  2014 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-60
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Mar 12  2014 /usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-60-generic-pae
```

I wonder if they are earlier versions of kernels that I can boot into, without making harm?

If yes, how can I boot into an earlier kernel version?

What does each directory having `-generic-pae` and not having it mean?
What is the difference between `linux-headers-3.2.0-59-generic-pae` and `linux-headers-3.2.0-59`?

Answer (score 1):

The PAE kernel means that you can use up to 64 GB of RAM even if you have a 32 Bit Linux. Furthermore, the kernel 3.2 is the lowest you can have in Ubuntu 12.04 except if you compile a lower one by yourself. This can be harmful since a lot of kernel modules and other packages relies on it.